# Tk window doesn't store variables?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Ok how do I make the user input something into a tk window to output it in a variable?
Ok so I am making an options menu for my program and I want to use the "answer" variable outside of the tk window. However, once the window closes, the variable becomes undefined. How do I make it save once the tk window closes so I can continue using it in the pygame window?

```
import pygame, time, math, sys
import tkinter as tk
from pygame.locals import *
from tkinter import *

def options():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x100")
    root.title('PyCott Options')

    

    def ctime():
        master = Tk()
        e = Entry(master)
        e.pack()
        

        e.focus_set()

        def callback():
            answer = (e.get())
            master.destroy()
            root.destroy()

        b = Button(master, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
        b.pack()

        master.mainloop()
        

    b = Button(text = "Change time", width = 10, command = ctime)
    b.pack()

    answer = e
    root.mainloop()

#Here, I open the option menu

options()

#However, here, even thought I defined it in the tk window, it becomes undefined outside of it
```

I know it's not really clear but I didn't manage to explain it better. Also, I am relatively new to python so some of this code is... Let's say I borrowed it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are receiving

```
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

this is because `e` is defined inside `ctime` which has not been invoked by the time `e` is first evaluated.

Comment: And how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

- better don't use `Tk()` for windows other than the root window.  Use `Toplevel()`
- need to add `nonlocal answer` inside `callback()` to indicate that `answer` is not a local variable inside `callback()`
- make the popup entry window like a modal dialog
- change `answer = e` to `answer = <whatever initial value you want>`
- return answer at the end of `options()`
- save the return value when calling `options()` and then you can use it elsewhere

Below is modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def options():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x100")
    root.title('PyCott Options')

    def ctime():
        master = Toplevel()  # use Toplevel() instead of Tk()

        e = Entry(master)
        e.pack()
        e.focus_set()

        def callback():
            nonlocal answer   # indicate that answer is not local variable
            answer = e.get()
            master.destroy()
            root.destroy()

        b = Button(master, text = "OK", width = 10, command = callback)
        b.pack()

        # make the popup as a modal dialog
        master.grab_set()


    b = Button(text = "Change time", width = 10, command = ctime)
    b.pack()

    answer = None   # initial value for answer, change to whatever you want
    root.mainloop()
    return answer

# store the return answer from options()
answer = options()
print(answer)
```